# Use keyup function in custom jQuery class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a custom jQuery class to create popup list, but when i pass the HTML elements to class objects is `undefined`!

I want to send element to class and set `.keyup()` event for that and manipulate element value in `.keyup()` function.

My code is:

```
$.Class('kpopup', {
    // static
    init: function (e, p, h, r, u) {
        url = u;
        hostElement = e;
        popupElement = p;
        popupResult = r;
        hiddenElement = h;

        $(hostElement).keyup(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { "value": $(hostElement).val() },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (dt) {
                    if (dt != "") {
                        $(popupResult).html(dt);
                        $(hostElement).popupDiv($(popupElement));
                    } else {
                        $(popupElement).hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
},
//Prototypes
{});
```

Code for using above class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var kpopup = new kpopup(
        $("#clas_academy_id"),
        $(".popup-picker"),
        $("#clas_academy_id_hidden"),
        $("#popup-result"),
        '@Url.Action("searchAcademies","Academy")'
    );
});
```

Comment: You're already passing jQuery objects to your class, so don't do things like this: `$(hostElement).val()`. Just do `hostElement.val()`.

Comment: i used that but has error `type error: hostElement.val is not a function`

Comment: Look at all the global variables! Why in the world would use not put the full variable names in the arguments to start out!

Comment: Where does $.Class come from? I'm trying to find it on the jquery documentation but am unable to find such a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, press F12 in chrome or control+shift+k in Firefox to open the console and inspect the output. You can click on some of the console.log outputs to inspect the values of the objects logged.

```
Kpopup = function(e, p, h, r, u) {
  console.log("creating Kpopup with parameters:", e, p, h, r, u);
  this.url = u;
  this.hostElement = e;
  this.popupElement = p;
  tis.popupResult = r;
  this.hiddenElement = h;
  this.init();
};
Kpopup.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log("And this is:", this);
  console.log("And this hostElement is:", this.hostElement);
  var pResult = this.popupResult;
  var hElement = this.hostElement;
  var pElement = this.popupElement;
  this.hostElement.keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.url,
      data: {"value": hElement.val()},
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(dt) {
        if (dt !== "") {
          pResult.html(dt);
          hElement.popupDiv(pElement);
        } else {
          pElement.hide();
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Note that I Capitalised your Kpopup object because that's the usual notation for constructor functions so your document ready you have to capitalise it as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var kpopup = new Kpopup(
        $("#clas_academy_id"),
        $(".popup-picker"),
        $("#clas_academy_id_hidden"),
        $("#popup-result"),
        '@Url.Action("searchAcademies","Academy")'
    );
});
```